# Copying codes in Google Colaboratory on iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use Google Colaboratory on iPhone and iPad. However, on safari and chrome, copying text cannot be done. Neither of touching screen, ctrl-c, cmd-c using external keyboard did work.
I would appreciate if you could kindly share your insights.